# progressbar for classic asp upload page?

Tags: asp-classic, progress-bar

I have a upload page done with classic asp and I want a progressbar.
Could be with jquery, ajax?

Does anyone know where I can find a solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot upload files using AJAX nor report the progress with javascript. There's a [jquery upload plugin](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-file-upload-plugin/) which supports this functionality and uses Flash behind the scenes to perform the upload and progress report.

Comment: Yes I have seen that one and it looks great, but that is with a php page aswell, and my server dont have support for php, and I dont know php programing. And it also use flash, and if I can I dont want to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at http://valums.com/ajax-upload/  It doesn't use flash (it is all based on DOM and javascript) and the upload script part can be adapted to any language (classic asp as well).

Comment: Thanks, yes it looks good, but I dont know if I will be able to seperate the progress part of it and adopt it to my upload script, since I dont want to change my uploading part, just get a progressbar to it.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but maybe still interesting:

http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/upload.asp

Is using a com component, works with classic asp. But this costs a few bucks (so it is commercial) and no, me are not related to this company, just a pleased customer.